# I have a .c.save file. What is it? What does it do?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am programming with C using Code::Blocks. My project is divided in 3, header, implementation and main.

Whenever I used a project, apart from the source files and the bin and obj folders I had a .depend and a .layout file. All good.

Now I created a new project, and just copied -> pasted everything new in source files. I did this twice.

For each case, I have a .c.save file, which has the same name of the implementation file (ie. the implementation file is called imp, then the file is called imp.c.save). I asked a friend of mine what it might be, and he said I need to beware as he had two random files created, which prevented him from building correctly (he got a stupid error). When the files were deleted everything went back to normal.

I did a short test of the program and I can find nothing different. I am hesitant to delete it since this cropped up twice in two cases, but I don't want to compromise my coding.

Tried to google and I didn't find much. Any help?

Comment: This is almost certainly an intermidiate or temporary save file generated by a text editor. It plays no role directly in the code compiled to create a library or application.

Comment: Google ".save" shows it is an [Autosaved](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-360001.11.15) file. Whether or not it causes the errors on your friend's computer is probably not related.

Comment: Er, why don't you just open the file and look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it didn't cause any problems so I assuming it is an autosave file.